# Install Canon isensys lbp6000 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, printing, lts

I need some exact steps to install this printer.
I did already download the driver from: https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6000.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 17ef:a360 Lenovo BillBoard Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04a9:271a Canon, Inc. LBP6000
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. Washable Keyboard K310
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:6044 Lenovo ThinkPad Laser Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded the `linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz` file form Canon.

This an archive. Open it by double-click and extract `Debian` from `64-bit Driver` directory to your Home.

Then open terminal and run:

```
cd Debian
sudo apt install ./cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I installed them. What next? I tried to search for printer under settings, but it only found a CUPS-BRF-Printer-2.

Comment: Now add a new printer. It is unclear what you searched. Go to Settings -> Printers -> Add new printer.

Comment: I did exactly this and then in will fire up a search for printers. CUPS-BRF-Printer is the name that comes up.

Comment: How is the printer connected?

Comment: It's connected via USB-cable.

Comment: If the printer is on and connected, you should see it there. If it is not there, please add output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: It's only the one I wrote above, it doesn't print out a test page however.

Comment: Try to reboot and then try to add the printer.

Comment: The only printer I can see is the one posted above as a screenshot. Printing a test-site won't work.